# Deleting previous signed APK after creating new APK?

Tags: android-studio

I am seeing an issue where Android Studio always deletes my previously created APK file when creating the new one???

Create Signed APK: Prog_v100.apk

Later I Create Signed APK: Prog_v101.apk … Prog_v100.apk will get deleted???

I looked and could not find a setting that governed this behavior???

Running AS 3.5.2

Thanks in advance

Marshall

Comment: Actually it is not get deleted. What happens is that it gets overwritten. If you want to save the previous apk you have to copy and paste it in somewhere else!

Comment: Curious??? I am naming the APK with the version number so that it will NOT be overwritten … so you're saying that it is still be overwritten???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traveling back in time ... From what I could find ... this is normal behavior of Android Studio. Almost like it deletes any APK in this target dir before creating the new APK. Good idea to move APK out of the target build dir after creation!